# "Nominate this question for reopening?" popup doesn't automatically close after voting

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-reopen, popup

If you click to reopen a question from the review queue, you get a popup with the title: "Nominate this question for reopening?".

[image: Nominate this question for reopening popup]

If you click "Vote to reopen" it casts your vote, the next question loads, but the popup stays on screen. You have to click "Cancel". Or if you click "Vote to reopen" the popup disappears and you see a little red popup:

[image: red popup "you have already voted to reopen"]

Seems like the first popup should disappear on its own. Presumably a bug. Pretty minor of course, but confusing.

I am running Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS 10.15.1 (19B88).